# Deep multibranch tree recursive javascript function is not keeping the parent reference

Tags: javascript

I have a dataset, which has the following structure:

```
...
{
    "id": "id"
    "name": "name" 
    "children": ["IdToChild", "IdToChild"]
}
... And so forth
```

The data will eventually construct a deep multi-branched tree. The flow is as follows:

1. Get parent object from database with child references
2. Get children from references
3. Append array of children to parent object
4. Proceed - If there are more child references¨

My objective is to have a complete tree with a structure similar to this:

```
{   
    "id": "myId"
    "name": "name 1",
    "children": '[
        {
            "id": "myId"
            "name": "name 2",
            "children": [
                {
                ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "myId"
            "name": "name 3",
            "children": [
                {
                ...
                },

            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I have the following code:

```
async function caller(){
    //Fetch parent object from database
    await assembletree(parentObj)
}

async function assembletree(parentObj){
    let childrenArray = []
 
    for(let index = 0; index < parentObj.children.length; index++){
        //Async call to database to get child object by id
        childrenArray.push(databaseObject)
    }
   
    //Remove existing children property that holds just the Ids
    delete parentObj.children

    //Assign the childrenArray to a new property named "children"
    Object.assign(parentObj, parentObj, {"children": childrenArray})

    //Initiate recursion to fetch next children
    for(let index = 0; index < parentObj.children.length; index++){
        await assembletree(parentObj.children[index]) // <--- 2nd child is never called
    }
}
```

When I have one single deep branch, it's really no problem with the above code. BUT when I encounter multiple children in a parent object, the code only proceeds recursion with the first child object.

When I debug my code, I can see that only the first child object correctly triggers the recursion loop, but the 2nd child object is never processed.

Naturally I'm unsure what I'm missing as everything seems valid to me. My initial guess to the above issue, is that the reference for some reason lose track of the 2nd child object.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the index in the line `await assembletree(parentObj.children)`? It looks like at each iteration of the loop you call this function on the same object

Comment: What's the initial call for `assembleTree`? The dataset seems overly elided -- maybe show a complete example with a nice representative example, and corresponding output expected for it.

Comment: @NinaLisitsinskaya yea sorry, I forgot about it in my question. I edited it. (still the same issue)

Comment: @ggorlen the original is similar, with the same amount of properties.

Comment: Can you not simply show it?  "I have a dataset, which has the following structure:" and I see one node with unclear structure I can't really work with or understand how it transforms into the shown output. If I don't know what's passed into `assembleTree` I can't run and reproduce the problem. Why are the db calls mixed in with the tree-building algorithm? Can you get the rows from the DB into a normal array, then create the tree from there? If not, I suggest mocking the async db call for the purposes of a [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen I edited my question (I was too quick putting in the Ids) - I cannot show the real data sorry. But it is similar. The database is a cosmos db.

Comment: I see you edited the question and added the `let` keyword to the second loop. Does the problem still exist even with the keyword there? If not you'll probably want to rollback the edit, since incorporating an answer into the question only causes confusion for other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to asynchronously load a tree, where the database responds with an element whose `children` node is merely an array of ids that you can then use to lookup again, then this will probably be fairly close:

```js
const loadTree = (id) => 
  db .lookup (id) .then (
    ({children, ...rest}) => 
      Promise.all (children .map (loadTree)) .then (children => ({... rest, children}))
  )

loadTree (3) 
  .then (console .log)
  .catch (console .warn)

loadTree (42) 
  .then (console .log)
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
// mocked database with a `lookup` call.
const db = ((nodes) => ({
  lookup: (id) => id in nodes 
    ? Promise.resolve (nodes [id]) 
    : Promise .reject (`id ${id} not found`)
}))({
  1: {name: 'test1', id: 1, children: [4, 5]},
  2: {name: 'test2', id: 2, children: []},
  3: {name: 'test3', id: 3, children: [7, 8]},
  4: {name: 'test1_1', id: 4, children: [6]},
  5: {name: 'test1_2', id: 5, children: []},
  6: {name: 'test1__1', id: 6, children: []},
  7: {name: 'test3_1', id: 7, children: []},
  8: {name: 'test3_2', id: 8, children: [9, 10]},
  9: {name: 'test3_2_1', id: 9, children: []},
  10: {name: 'test3_2_2', id: 10, children: []},
})
</script>
```

Notice that `db .lookup` is simply a hard-coded dummy to return a Promise for a `{name, id, children}` structure based on the id supplied, rejecting if it's not found.  So the only important thing here is `loadTree`, which calls `db.lookup` for the node supplied, then recursively maps `loadTree` over the children, combines them with `Promise.all`, and creates an output object with these and the rest of your nodes.

There are plenty of changes we might want to see.  Perhaps we shouldn't reject when the id is not found, but return an empty object or `undefined`.  Perhaps we want the `children` node only if it's non-empty.  And there are many more such possibilities.  But this might be a decent start.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is the second for-loop:

> ```
> for(index = 0; index < parentObj.children.length; index++){
> ```

**You forgot the `let` keyword before `index`.** The consequence is that you are now using the global variable `index` which is shared with recurring calls.

With `let` added your code seems to seems to work fine:

```js
async function assembletree(parentObj){
    let childrenArray = []
 
    for(let index = 0; index < parentObj.children.length; index++){
        //Async call to database to get child object by id
        const databaseObject = await fetchDatabaseObject(parentObj.children[index]);
        childrenArray.push(databaseObject)
    }
   
    //Remove existing children property that holds just the Ids
    delete parentObj.children

    //Assign the childrenArray to a new property named "children"
    Object.assign(parentObj, parentObj, {"children": childrenArray})

    //Initiate recursion to fetch next children
    // Added the let keyword below!
    for(let index = 0; index < parentObj.children.length; index++){
        await assembletree(parentObj.children[index]) // <--- 2nd child is now called
    }
}

(async function () {
  try {
    const object = await fetchDatabaseObject(1);
    await assembletree(object);
    console.log(object);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
})();

// mock data/database
const records = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "a" ,
  "children": [2, 3],
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "b" ,
  "children": [4],
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "c" ,
  "children": [5],
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "d" ,
  "children": [],
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "name": "e" ,
  "children": [],
}];
const indexed = new Map(records.map(record => [record.id, record]));

async function fetchDatabaseObject(id) {
  await sleep(100);
  return deepDupplicate(indexed.get(id));
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function deepDupplicate(object) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
}
```

There are quite a few optimisations that can be made, but I'll leave those out of the focus of the answer.